# Is there a hypervisor that meets these goals?

Tags: windows, linux

I mostly run Windows 10 but also need full featured Linux (Ubuntu probably) so I can work with Linux Raspbian formatted mSD cards and USB sticks for ARM development as well as for Linux testing scenarios.

Below are my Desktop Development Environment Goals I would like to meet with a Class 1 or 2 Hypervisor on my desktop that has an i7 and 32G memory=>

I want to do all the below on one physical machine w/o requiring a second machine to connect to the guest VMs or to manage the VMs or the hypervisor.

Ideally install a class 1 hypervisor such as free Hyper-V, free vSphere, KVM/Qemu, Xen that met the below goals. I would certainly consider a class 2 hypervisor if it met all the below goals. Probably there would be no video concern with a Class 2 but but split memory and USB pass-through are concerns!

Ideal would be to auto convert the current Win10 to a VM guest during installation but there are ways around this so not required but would be a good sales feature for a hv vendor that wanted to market to the desktop user.

Ideally all/most of my memory (32G) to be available to a select VM (or hypervisor host) if not needed by other VMs. If I remember right, early Win10 with Hyper-V made me split memory between Windows and Hyper-V usage.

Especially need support for native use of USB to Linux in order to support partition formats that Windows does not such as > 32G FAT32 or ext4. Windows File Manager repeatedly crashes if you insert a mSD or USB that has Linux partitions on it. Shame on MSFT since Windows just formatted the device with Etcher! AFAIK Windows 10 w/ Hyper-V still uses the Windows disk manager and file manager which does not do well with Linux formatted mSD cards and USB sticks.

If a Class 1, all of the following would be desirable -

Option for dedicated GPU video of the desktop machine to a preferred VM so get better performance than RDP from the same or another PC.

Local hypervisor UI so can manage VMs w/o a second physical machine. Also a good sales feature for a hv vendor that wanted to market to the desktop user.

Local Hypervisor UI that allows using the local machine's video, mouse, and keyboard, or at least RDP/VNC, in order connect to a guest machine on the desktop w/o needing another remote machine to do so. Another good sales feature for a hv vendor that wanted to market to the desktop user.

Were it not for the Hyper-V split memory issue, and especially lack of USB pass-through, I would be happy enough with Windows 10 with the Hyper-V feature turned on. I had it setup a while back but having to split the memory between Win10 and Hyper-V was a turnoff.

This is not a a search for opinions! I just want to know what hypervisors, if any, can meet the requirements for my specific development needs.

Thanks for any input on this, Dave